# Remote Access to Kubernetes API Without the Proxy

Tags: python, x509certificate, kubernetes, client-certificates

I am trying to gain remote access to the Kubernetes API (primarily from our Jenkins server) so we can perform RESTful actions and not rely on `kubectl`.  Ideally, I'd like to do this in Go or Python but none of the libraries I have tried have been successful, and using `urllib2` directly returns a variety of errors.  I have been able to connect via curl (albeit with some weird errors as well) but I was hoping to not have to form curl GET/PUT requests for all of this.

So my question is: can some kind soul (perhaps someone from Google?) outline the steps I need to properly auth with the Kubernetes API server from a remote location?  Any guidance is greatly appreciate as I am interested in learning more about x509 but am struggling to tie all of the pieces together.

**Curl structure which *basically* works**

These .pem files were manually created from the values in `~/.kube/config`

```
$ curl --header "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" -key key.pem -cacert ca.pem -cert client.pem https://MASTER_IP/api
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: key.pem
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: ca.pem
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: client.pem
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "172.20.0.9:443"
    }
  ]
}
```

**4/14/2016 Update**
So it seems that I needed to rename some of these as .crt files.  After reading about potential issues with curl, I gave wget a go and it seems to have no problems, without even specifying an auth header.  Any insight into client based authentication is appreciated.

```
$ wget -qO- https://MASTER_IP/api --certificate client-decoded.crt --private-key clean-key.pem --ca-certificate ca.crt
{
  "kind": "APIVersions",
  "versions": [
    "v1"
  ],
  "serverAddressByClientCIDRs": [
    {
      "clientCIDR": "0.0.0.0/0",
      "serverAddress": "172.20.0.9:443"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you're missing a dash on --key, --cacert, and --cert args, and may also need to specify the cert as ./client.pem

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the client libraries supported (https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/docs/devel/client-libraries.md).

To connect with the official Go client something like this should work, you can easily pass in a kubeCfgFile and then the client will use that to connect:

```
func newKubeClient() (*kclient.Client, error) {
    var (
        config    *kclient.Config
        err       error
        masterURL string
    )

    if *argKubeMasterURL != "" {
        masterURL, err = expandKubeMasterURL()

        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    if masterURL != "" && *argKubecfgFile == "" {
        config = &kclient.Config{
            Host:    masterURL,
            Version: "v1",
        }
    } else {
        overrides := &kclientcmd.ConfigOverrides{}
        overrides.ClusterInfo.Server = masterURL
        rules := &kclientcmd.ClientConfigLoadingRules{ExplicitPath: *argKubecfgFile}
        if config, err = kclientcmd.NewNonInteractiveDeferredLoadingClientConfig(rules, overrides).ClientConfig(); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    glog.Infof("Using %s for kubernetes master", config.Host)
    glog.Infof("Using kubernetes API %s", config.Version)
    return kclient.New(config)
}
```